# custom zsh completion based on multiple paths

Tags: zsh

I want to write a custom completion for a command that accepts a directory as an argument. I think it's easiest to explain how it is supposed to work with an example.

Let's assume I have a list of directories defined somewhere:

```
d=(~/somedir/foo ~/somedir/foo/bar ~/other/dir/baz)
```

Valid calls to the command are

```
mycmd foo
mycmd bar
mycmd baz
mycmd baz/and/some/subdir
```

The completion should be able to do

```
mycmd f<TAB>              => mycmd foo
mycmd baz/and/some/s<TAB> => mycmd baz/and/some/subdir
```

Somehow I'm a bit lost in the complexity of zshcompsys, so I'm not really sure how to approach this best.

Comment: Does the list of directories defined in `d` have a relation to the completion? Your example isn't very clear on that. Are the arguments fixed (so you can hardwrite them into the completion function), or variable (based on the contents of a directory)?

Comment: Sorry that this wasn't clear. d does define some kind of search path. For example the entry "~/other/dir/baz" means that "baz" is a valid argument, but so is also "baz/subdir" assuming "~/other/dir/baz/subdir" exists.

Comment: So this means that I need to use some kind of two-leveled approach. For the first part it should be enough to provide a list of the trailing parts (== $entry(:d)). For the second part, i.e. to complete "baz/s<TAB>" I first need to find out that "baz" actually refers to "~/other/dir/baz" and complete based on the subdirectories found in there.

I hope this makes it a little clearer.

Answer (score 8):

#### 1. Pre-defined directories as arguments.

If you know in advance what the arguments of `mycmd` can be, you can just use a very simple completion function with the values hard-coded inside:

```
 #compdef _mycmd
 _arguments "1: :(foo bar baz baz/and/some/subdir)"
```

This gives the following:

```
zsh% mycmd<TAB>
bar                    baz                    baz/some/other/subdir  foo    
zsh% mycmd baz<TAB>
baz                    baz/some/other/subdir
zsh% mycmd baz/<TAB>
zsh% mycmd baz/some/other/subdir
```

#### 2. Completion to all subdirectories within a directory

Assuming that any subdirectory of `foo` is a valid path for `mycmd`:

```
~/foo/bar         # Valid path
~/foo/subdir/baz  # Valid path
~/baz/bar         # Invalid path
```

you can tell `compctl` to complete any directory within `foo` as an argument to `mycmd`:

```
# In your ~/.zshrc
compctl -/ -W ~/foo mycmd
```

I do not know how well this will play with any other completion function for `mycmd` that you have written (for example, if `mycmd` also takes non-filename arguments). It completes like this:

```
zsh% mycmd<TAB>
bar/  baz/  caz/
zsh% mycmd baz/s<TAB>
zsh% mycmd baz/subdir/
```

#### Note: my paths / commands got a bit long. I've snipped some in the below pastes (replaced with `...`).

#### 3. Using pre-defined arrays.

If we have an array `d=(foo bar baz)`, where each element is a valid completion for `mycmd`, we can use `-k`:

```
→ compctl -k "(foo bar baz)" mycmd
→ mycmd
bar  baz  foo
```

#### 4. Subdirectories of arrays.

Using the following directory structure:

```
~/.../somedir
~/.../somedir/bar
~/.../somedir/foo
~/.../somedir/foo/invalid
~/.../otherdir
~/.../otherdir/subdir
~/.../otherdir/subdir/baz
```

The `-W` option of `compctl` also takes an array as an argument, allowing this:

```
→ compctl -/ -W "(/.../otherdir /.../somedir)" mycmd
→ mycmd <TAB>
bar/     foo/     subdir/
```

I'm fairly sure this now matches to what you want.
**Note:** The `-W` option works with the `-/` (read the man page for `zshcompctl`) - `-W` doesn't work on it's own.

#### 5. Arrays with partial subdirectories

Let's assume that valid arguments are:

```
mycmd foo  # Valid
mycmd baz  # Valid
mycmd baz/and/some/subdir # Valid - subdirectory of `baz`
mycmd foo/subdir # Invalid!!
```

where we do **not** want subdirectories of `foo`, only of `baz`. We can achieve this by mixing `-k` and `-/ -W`:

```
→ compctl -/ -W "(/.../otherdir)" -k "(/.../somedir/foo)" mycmd
→ mycmd <TAB>
/Users/simont/sandbox/completion/somedir/foo  subdir/ 
→ mycmd foo/<TAB> # No further completion - we can't complete foo/invalid. 
→ mycmd subdir/<TAB>
→ mycmd subdir/baz/
```

This, however, leaves the full path to `foo` (unlike `-W`, which removes it). To fix this, don't put it into the array for `-k`:

```
compctl -/ -W "(/.../otherdir)" -k "(foo)" mycmd
```

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! :) Unfortunately I need a way to combine both methods. See the reply to your other comment for details.

Comment: @dani_l Hopefully this works for you. I've learned a whole bunch - never played with `compctl` before.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your help, simont, but I took another approach using a completion function. It's mostly based on trial and error rather than reading the documentation, so I have no idea if this is the right way[tm] to do it, but it works and does not require much code.

```
function _foo {
    setopt LOCALOPTIONS
    unsetopt AUTOPUSHD
    local paths
    paths=(/home/dani '/var/log' '/usr/share' '/etc')

    if [[ $PREFIX == *'/'* ]] {
        for p ($paths) {
            if [[ ${PREFIX[(ws:/:)1]} == ${p:t} ]] {
                local oldpwd=$PWD
                cd -q ${p:h}
                local matches
                matches=($PREFIX*(/))
                 if [[ ${#matches} -gt 0 ]] {
                    compadd -p ${matches[1]:h}'/' -q -S '/' -- ${matches:t}
                }
                cd -q $oldpwd
                return
            }
        }
    } else {
        compadd -q -S '/' -- ${^paths:t}
    }
}

compdef _foo foo
```